# Collapsible Folder

Tags: jquery, css

**Problem:** I was able to create a collapsible folder with the css.

However, I am not able to determine how to push down the folder if it goes to the second page. Currently, how the CSS is working, it will overlap if there is a folder below the folder that is beneath it. I would like to be able to push the folder below another folder down.

I have provided an image on what I am talking about:

[image]

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left:20px">
      <a href="#">Controlled Substance Materials</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
       </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
      </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
     </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
   <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left:20px">
      <a href="#">Controlled Substance Materials</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
       </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
      </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
     </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>   
   <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left:20px">
      <a href="#">Controlled Substance Materials</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
       </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
      </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
     </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
               <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left:20px">
      <a href="#">Controlled Substance Materials</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
       </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
      </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
     </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
```

Comment: It's not good approach to state `id="primary_nav_wrap"` more than once in the html. If you use it more than once, it should be a class

Comment: @Banzay: You are correct. I thought I was did a class

Comment: I would suggest using position: relative for first-level sub-menus, and maybe leave absolute positioning for deeper sub-menus

Comment: This is best done with JS, but one way you could do this is to set the height of the <li> element you want to expand to a fixed value, approximately equal to the line height for the collapsible folder line, and apply overflow: hidden to it. Then you could add a :hover state to the <li> that adjusts the height to reveal the rest of the menu items.

Comment: Are you really sure this is the approach you want to take? It seems that the sub items of the top folder would never be accessible, as you'd have to mouse "through" the folder below it to ever click on the sub items. It also doesn't seem like easily understandable UI to have subitems not be directly connected in some way to the parent item. I think instead, I'd apply a background to the sub item list and have it positioned just as it currently is.

Comment: @JesseRogers @ Armin @ GregBurkett: can you please provide an example

Comment: Here is an example of my suggestion, but I agree with others that this is not the best approach: https://jsfiddle.net/3r2af4by/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it if I really only wanted to use CSS. I've included comments in the CSS to explain what I'm doing.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.collapsible {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 24px; /* Fixed value for height */
  overflow: hidden; /* hides the Sub-items */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 6px;
  width: 160px;
}
.collapsible:hover {
  cursor: pointer !important; /* For easier user interaction */
  height: auto; /* On hover, the full menu is revealed */
}
.collapsible li {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px; /* Line height is just greater than the height of the menu before hover to make sure it's hidden */
}
.collapsible li:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
  }
.collapsible li:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  }
.folder-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="collapsible">
  <li class="folder-title">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVYiGGwOeG9r4CWQgttlHyby_BMVa_mx7qZW9yFt5nFifCvRtj_Kt40Q" style="height: 16px; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;Folder Title</li>
  <li>Sub-item 1</li>
  <li>Sub-item 2</li>
  <li>Sub-item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="collapsible">
  <li class="folder-title">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVYiGGwOeG9r4CWQgttlHyby_BMVa_mx7qZW9yFt5nFifCvRtj_Kt40Q" style="height: 16px; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;Folder Title</li>
  <li>Sub-item 1</li>
  <li>Sub-item 2</li>
  <li>Sub-item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="collapsible">
  <li class="folder-title">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVYiGGwOeG9r4CWQgttlHyby_BMVa_mx7qZW9yFt5nFifCvRtj_Kt40Q" style="height: 16px; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;Folder Title</li>
  <li>Sub-item 1</li>
  <li>Sub-item 2</li>
  <li>Sub-item 3</li>
</ul>


<ul class="collapsible">
  <li class="folder-title">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVYiGGwOeG9r4CWQgttlHyby_BMVa_mx7qZW9yFt5nFifCvRtj_Kt40Q" style="height: 16px; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;Folder Title</li>
  <li>Sub-item 1</li>
  <li>Sub-item 2</li>
  <li>Sub-item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Basically, use `overflow: hidden;` and a fixed `height` value to hide the rest of the `<li>` items, and use a `:hover` state to reveal them. The change in height will push the other folders down as well.