# How to push down <li> when showing hidden div?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do something but not sure if it is possible.

I have several *li* and inside each of them I have a hidden *div* with additional content. When I click on the *li* the *div* is shown right below the *li* and with a 100% width. The problem I have is that the content is placed over the other *divs* instead of pushing them down. I know using absolute position is never going to push the content down but I don't know how to give it a 100% width then.

I'd like to place the hidden *div* below the *li*, occupying 100% width of the window and then place the other *li*, if any, below the content. So, if I click on any *li* in the first row, the hidden div will be displayed below this row and *li* in the second row will be displayed right after the *div*.

You can see the code I have  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/zah1w8L0/1/)

Any change on `JS` or `CSS`is welcome

I hope I've explained it well. Could you gimme hand with this, please?

Many thanks!

```js
$('.workContent').hide();

$('.containerGrid').click(function() {

  $('.workContent').hide();
  var idProject = $(this).parent().attr('data-content');
  $(idProject).show();

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #00ff24;
}

li.grid:hover {
  background-color: #99f4a6;
}

.containerGrid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.containerGrid h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.workContent {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="grid" data-content="#project1">
      <div class="containerGrid">
        <h2>Title grid</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="project1" class="workContent">
        <p>Content 1</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="grid" data-content="#project2">
      <div class="containerGrid">
        <h2>Title grid</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="project2" class="workContent">
        <p>Content 2</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="grid" data-content="#project3">
      <div class="containerGrid">
        <h2>Title grid</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="project3" class="workContent">
        <p>Content 3</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="grid" data-content="#project4">
      <div class="containerGrid">
        <h2>Title grid</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="project4" class="workContent">
        <p>Content 4</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="grid" data-content="#project5">
      <div class="containerGrid">
        <h2>Title grid</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="project5" class="workContent">
        <p>Content 5</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="grid" data-content="#project6">
      <div class="containerGrid">
        <h2>Title grid</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="project6" class="workContent">
        <p>Content 6</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="grid" data-content="#project7">
      <div class="containerGrid">
        <h2>Title grid</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="project7" class="workContent">
        <p>Content 7</p>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I posted an answer recently  on another question that is very similar to this. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231351/collapsible-folder/42234285#42234285

I wouldn't necessarily do it entirely my way since that guy wanted a solution with no JS, but the fixed height and `overflow: hidden;` techniques should carry over if you apply them to your hidden div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jesse.

I had a look to the issue you mentioned but unfortunately doesn't fix my issue. That guy have li nested in different ul plus I need a 100% width, I have applied that changes to my hidden divs as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/zah1w8L0/2/ but nothing change. I can use JS if you think is a better way to do this. Any idea? Thanks again, mate.

Comment: Okay, I have a clearer idea of what you're trying to do now. I think the biggest obstacle in your way is that you're using `.parent().attr('data-content')` which is forcing you to structure your HTML in a way that is making this hard.

I'm not a JS expert, but from an HTML and CSS standpoint, I can tell you that pulling `.workContent` out of the `<li>` and putting it on the same hierarchical level as `li.grid` will make it easier.

Also, `position: fixed;` is not the only way to get 100%. `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` will work too.

Comment: Hi, Jesse. thanks for your comment.  I've tried that option before but, unfortunately, I need to keep the hidden div inside the li because I will add other elements inside the hidden dv in future such as next and previous navigation buttons that will allow me to navigate between contents once they have been displayed. I'm working on Andrei's suggestions via jquery. I will keep you posted. Many thanks again, mate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this responsively:

- give the parent `display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`
- using a `while` and `.next()` go to following siblings after the clicked item (`$(e.target)`) until you find the one that's starting a new row (you could use `.position()` to determine this) or, alternatively, to determine if you are on last row of children
- When you've reached the first item of next row, `.insertBefore()` it a div with `flex-basis: 100%;`. Populate it with the desired content, either by cloning it from the clicked div or generating it on the fly (that's how i'd do it).
- don't forget to remove all the "big" (`flex-basis:100%`) children whenever you click on a new child and are about to insert a new "big one"
- don't forget to also cover the case when you're on the last row (you run out of siblings without getting on a new row).

I promise I'll finish and streamline it for you, explaining if and what you did wrong. But I want you to try your hand at it and show your approach/best attempt. You're here to learn and get better. Remember, `console.log()` is your best friend.

---

```js
$('.expandables').on('click', '.item', function(e){
  // remove any open items
  removeItem($('.expandables>.content'));

  var item = $(e.target).closest('.item'), // clicked item
      content = item.find('.content'), // content
      nextItem = item.next(), 
      nextItemPosition = nextItem.position(); 
  while (nextItemPosition && (nextItemPosition.left > 20)) {
    // if no next, nextItemPosition will be undefined
    // if nextItemPosition.left is bigger than 1rem, we're not at start of row
    nextItem = nextItem.next(); //move to next item
    nextItemPosition = nextItem.position(); //set new position
  }

  if (nextItem.is('.item')) {
    // we're at the start of a new row
    content.clone().insertBefore(nextItem);  
  } else {
    // we reached the end of .expandables without finding a new row
    content.clone().appendTo($('.expandables'))
  }
})
function removeItem(item) {
  // Function to remove items (needed for animation purposes)
  // and in your case it needs to match the same animation for 
  // opening, if you want them synced.
  item.remove(); 
}

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  // remove any open items
  removeItem($('.expandables>.content'));
})
```

```css
.expandables {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.expandables > div {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 1rem);
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .expandables > div {
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 1rem);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.expandables > div {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 1rem);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 539px) {
  .expandables > div {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 1rem);
  }
}
.expandables > div > .content {
  display: none;
}
.expandables > .content {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 1rem);
}

/* above are just basics, covering positioning and layout 
 * below is a little basic styling
 */
body {margin:0;} *{box-sizing: border-box;}
.expandables {
  padding: .5rem;
}
.expandables>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: .5rem;
}
.expandables>.content {
  background-color: #787878;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandables">
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h2>Title grid 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h2>Title grid 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h2>Title grid 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h2>Title grid 4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h2>Title grid 5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h2>Title grid 6</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h2>Title grid 7</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content 7</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Final version, with open/close [`animations`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/azacqetz/embedded/result/#Result).

Also note CSS should be [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)ed  before deploying. If you want max browser compatibility, you wan to set it to `> 0%` (in the tiny box at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrei. That's my goal too, keep on learning instead of looking for a piece of code that fix the job, I really appreciate your words.
I've been trying your suggestions by reading some documentation. Mostly of the concepts you mentioned are new for me.

Comment: First thing I'm trying to do is to understand the logic of your approach. What you're suggesting, unless I'm wrong, is to check if the li where I click on is the first li of a row and, if so, add a new div with flex-basis:100% that will open a gap where I can place the content of the hidden div. Keep in mind the number of li per row could change depending on the window size due to li width will change to make it responsively. I haven't achieved what I was looking for yet perhaps because of I'm using all the elements wrongly. This is what I got so far https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/zah1w8L0/3/

Comment: By the way, you won't see the console.log in the jsfiddle because it doesn't help me, however I'm using it locally this way 

console.log($(this).parent('li').index()); 

which returns the number of li I click on (not sure how to use this information tbh XD). Just wanted to let you know I'm trying to use all the elements you said.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: [so] is actually quite well prepared for this by allowing me to create a chat room where we can have the discussion. However, it doesn't seem to give me (or I haven't been able to find it yet) a way to directly create a room and post the link here. It will just detect based on number of comments and at some point it will pop me a message saying: avoid long discussions in chat, create a room. Until it does that, I'm going to just edit the answer post with answers to your questions.

Comment: I'm a newcomer here at Stack Overflow and there are many things here I don't know how to do. Wouldn't like to create a never ending conversation tho.

So, the first thing I did wrong was to add display:flex; flex-wrap; to the li element instead to the ul, am I wrong? Then I need to find the last child on the row and then add the div with flex-basis:100% where I will place the content of the hidden div, right?

Comment: I updated the answer with a working code. As much as possible, I tried to build it in steps (both `js` and `css`), so you understand what each does. If anything doesn't make sense, just go to jQuery docs and look at the method I used. I'm now working on final step (animating it, so it's complete). I changed your markup to one that made more sense. For example, there's no point in using `<ul>`s just to fight default styling of `<ul>`s

Comment: Awesome Andrei! Dunno what to say, I was trying something more difficult. I'm going to try to learn your code and look for some documentation for those elements are not clear enough. Thanks a mil for your support and help, Andrei. I don't know how to rate you here but I will find it out and give max posible.

Comment: Hi again, Andrei. Sorry for bothering you with this one more time. Could please gimme some clues in case I want to add some navigation button inside the content displayed. I've changed your content to make more usable by changing active item status and adding some buttons, but I can't make the next and previous thing and I find myself bit lost and would appreciate some advices from a guru like you. This is the code I have now based on yours https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/rdzm2gj1/14/ many thanks again

Comment: You're not respecting the first principle of programming: DRY. ***Don't repeat yourself.***. Don't put buttons in all content, if everything those buttons will ever do is the same function (close, goLeft or goRight). You put them in a hidden container somewhere and copy them on the fly to any open div. Tomorrow, when you will need a fourth button (maybe share?) you will only need to add it to the hidden container, instead of every single content `<div>`. Even your structure is too repetitive and should actually be generated on the fly, using a single pattern. I'll update but can't right now.

Comment: I know, I need to improve the procedure. Lemme see how I can make it less repetitive. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @tanaan This is the markup: `<expandables></expandables>`. And this is [`the result`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/7uwzme99/embedded/result/#Result). You can inspect/fork, whatever. Take care.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Andrei.
I will have a look to this new approach, it is quite different from what we've been working on. I understand this method makes the code cleaner, however, do you think that include the entire content in the JS file would be the best idea in terms of SEO and indexation?

Comment: Google is able to render the entire page and read the DOM, thereby indexing dynamically generated content. AngularJs is ***only*** generated content. AngularJs is Google. They've been parsing `js` since before 2010. I showed how to do it. You can skip the generating part :). I just find it cleaner. SEO is the same.

Comment: I see, I'm quite far to understand all of this I think :) It's going to take me a while, but again... the goal here is to learn and no just copy and paste. I obviously did the content bit more complicated because was trying to change how the div selected looks once is active, but I'll try to implement that in your awesome code. Feel bad for bothering you that much, I really appreciate your time and help, mate.

Comment: I'm no coder. A bit over 8 years ago all code was mambo-jambo to me. It's only one principle you need to stick to: DRY. If you're writing the same thing in the same app more than 3 times and it's more than 2 lines long, you're doing it wrong. The rest, comes and goes. It's just methods, properties. Doors you open/close. What you want is the handle.

Comment: hehe I'm not a coder as you probably already noticed. But want to learn. I guess is a matter of time and practice. To read documentation is easy, but then you face "real problems" and is when the troubles show up. I'll try my best to adapt you code to my needs following your advices. This last one just blown my mind cuz I was taking a different approach. I'll see where I end up. They've been really useful.

Comment: Andrei mate, sorry for bothering you again. It is just one small YES/NO question, feel free to answer. I like your last approach a lot but was wondering if is posible to load a HTML inside the div.content. You adding some simple text to that div but I'd like to know if is posible to load a HTML structure from an external file. Probably by storing it in a variable and pass this variable to e.content. Just wondering... thanks and sorry for the inconvenience again.

Comment: Yes, totally possible. When you create an HTML element using jQuery's method : `$('<eelement />', {})`, in the properties object, use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and you can put as much HTML code there as you want. `.html()` defaults to `.text()` when you only input text, as you'd expect. So I personally use `.html()` all the time, except when I put there stuff I don't trust and I don't want to allow `html`. You already have the example of how it's done there, in `clone` and `item` variables.

Comment: Yup, I think I haven't explained myself properly. What I tried to say is if is posible to have a different HTML file (lets say content1.html) and load it inside your `<div class="content">` in index.html . The idea is to generate the items and HTML structure the way you did (because is so repetitive as you said) and have other HTML files in a different folder where we can create the content needed for each item. So if I need to add new Item, I just will include it inside the `main` variable, then I will create the content in a different HTML file and will load it inside `.content`.

Comment: I have tried `$( ".content" ).load( "content1.html" );` but it doesn't work. This thing does something similar `<function load_home() { document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="content1.html" ></object>'; }`but includes an object with `<head> <body>` and the result is not too nice. I will keep on investigating. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you should read carefully the doc at [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). You're making an ajax call, it's not a template inclusion. It doesn't work like AngularJs templates or how web components will work. It makes an XHR call and parses the response, you need to tell it what to do with the result. I also think you should consider asking properly documented questions each time you need an answer. When I answer to you here, I only help you. If it was a different question, I would help many more.

Comment: You are right, you've been very kind with me and I probably abusing now through my ignorance. Please accept my sincere apologies, Andrei.